# Div bootstrap positioning

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with positioning `div`s. I'd like to show an image of what I want to obtain, but I haven't got enough reputation to do so. So, I'll explain like this:

```
 _____________________________________
|  ____                               | 
| |img | Name             Price       |
| |____| Description      Add to cart |
|_____________________________________|
```

This is my code:

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="pull-left"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/" + element.ProductId + ".jpg")" class="img-thumbnail" height="100" width="100" /></div>
    <div class="pull-left">
        <span class="pull-left">@Html.Label(element.Name) @element.Category</span>
        <span class="pull-right">@element.Price.ToString("C")</span>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <span class="pull-left">@element.Description</span>
        <span class="pull-right">@Html.ActionLink("Do koszyka", "AddToCart", "Cart", new { element.ProductId, returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and html code:

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="pull-left"><img src="/Content/Images/13.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" height="100" width="100" /></div>
    <div class="pull-left">
        <span class="pull-left"><label for="Dysk_SSD_Kingston_60GB_V300_SATA3">Dysk SSD Kingston 60GB V300 SATA3</label> Dyski SSD</span>
        <span class="pull-right">199,00 zł</span>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <span class="pull-left">Kingston</span>
        <span class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-default" href="/Cart/AddToCart?ProductId=13&amp;returnUrl=%2F">Do koszyka</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't work the way I want it to. I don't know what should I change.

Comment: If it "doesn't work", let us know what the actual problem is. Tell us what you've tried to solve it and why your solutions didn't work. In addition, it'd help if you stick with just the front-end bit and give us rendered html instead of an unparsed Razor view.

Comment: You mean something like this? http://www.bootply.com/BuMrShadVw

Comment: Great! Now looks really good, but is there any chance to be Name and Price on the same level?

Comment: Try it now. Remove the pull-right, not keen on it really.

Comment: Removing pull-right doesn't work, website bootply.com/BuMrShadVw also doesn't work

Comment: Checkout my answer below and let me know if this is what you want .

Comment: Thanks for help! Now elements are in the same level, but are both on the left side, instead "Price", and "Add to Cart" on the right side. Now I'm just not understanding css... btw I can't remember when Nicholas was so young ;)

Answer (score 0):

Could you check this out.
I have inserted a row within the well. and created a bootstrap 3 column grid wiht in the row.

Please check out the code demo in the below fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/YameenYasin/38gudt6s/1/

```
<div class="well">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 pull-left"><img src="/Content/Images/13.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" height="100" width="100" /></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 pull-left">
        <span class="pull-left"><label for="Dysk_SSD_Kingston_60GB_V300_SATA3">Product Name goes here</span>
        <span class="pull-left">Product Description</span>        
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 pull-right">

        <span >Price: 199,00 zł</span>
        <span><a class="btn btn-default" href="/Cart/AddToCart?ProductId=13&amp;returnUrl=%2F">Add to Cart</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But hovewer it works for low resolution, in 1920x1080 all elements are in the same level.